# what is the meaning of !: in this entity description?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, entity, typeorm

In another question people were using `!:` in an entiy description.
what is the meaning of `!:` ?
example:

```
@Column({
    type: 'text',
    unique: true,
    nullable: true,
})
resetPasswordToken!: string;
```

i think `?:` means its an optional parameter, but what is the meaning of `!:` ?

Comment: That looks to be TypeOrm syntax and Typescript. In TS The !: denotes it is a non-nullable value.